# C++ template class specialization constructor

Tags: templates, c++17, template-specialization

I want to create a generic Vector class like this `Vector<int Dimension, typename Type>`. And this is my code:

```cpp
template <int Dimension, typename Type>
class Vector
{
public:
  Vector() 
    : _data {} 
  {}
  Vector(const std::array<Type, Dimension>& init)
    : _data {init}
  {}
  ...
protected:
 std::array<Type, Dimension> _data;
};
```

With that declaration, i can initialize my vector with a `std::array`.

```cpp
Vector<3, float> vec({1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f});
// or like this
Vector<3, float> vec = {{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}};
```

But now i want my vector has a better constructor for some common vector type like Vec1, Vec2, Vec3, ...
I have tried to create a recursion template class to add an additional constructor for each of them:

```cpp
template <typename Type>
class Vector<3, Type>
{
public:
  Vector(const Type& x, const Type& y, const Type& z)
    : _data {x, y, z}
  {}
};
```

But when i compile my program i received this error:

```
error C3861: '_data': identifier not found
```

My questtion are:

- Why this error happen?
- And how can i add an additional constructor for some common template of my `Vector`.

PS: Sorry if my English is hard to understand ‍♀️.

Comment: There is no recursion here. `Vector<3, Type>` is a wholly independent thing, unrelated to the generic `Vector<Dimension, Type>`. It does not contain any `_data` or anything else that the main template contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why?

There is no recursion here. `Vector<3, Type>` is a wholly independent thing, unrelated to the generic `Vector<Dimension, Type>`. It does not contain any `_data` or anything else that the main template contains.

### How?

You don't need recursion or specialisation here, you need a forwarding constructor.

```
  template <int Dimension, typename Type>
  class Vector
  {
    public:
      template <typename ... T>
      Vector(T&& ... t) 
        : _data{std::forward<T>(t)...} {}
  
    protected:
      std::array<Type, Dimension> _data;
  };
```

This is the only constructor you need. It basically says "initialise Vector with whatever you can initialise _data". So you can have:

```
Vector<4, int> v4(1,2,3,4);
Vector<2, int> v2{1,2};

std::array<float, 3> u3 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
Vector<3, float> v3{u3};

Vector<5, float> v5;
```

### Is this all?

No. Perhaps you do need to add some functionality to `Vector<3,Type>` which is not present in the main template. In this case you can use inheritance.

- Rename your `Vector` class template to `VectorBase`
- Create a new `Vector` class template that inherits from ``VectorBase` and uses its constructor, and does nothing more:

  ```
  template <int Dimension, typename Type>
  class Vector : public VectorBase<Dimension, Type> {
     public:
         using VectorBase<Dimension, Type>::VectorBase;
  };
  ```
- Now you can specialise `Vector` and add functionality to it. You need to repeat the `using` declaration in every specialisation, but that's not too much boilerplate.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Your suggestions are actually work. But when i use `Vector<3, float> vec {1, 2, 3}`, my compiler says: `error C2397: conversion from '_Ty' to '_Ty' requires a narrowing conversion.` And my IDE says: `In template: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'float' in initializer list.` Why it happens?

Comment: This is how curly braces work in initialisation. It is not easy to fix, but you can use the second part of the solution and add a custom constructor in the derived class.